# Tensorflow JS transform 1d tensor into 2d tensor structured as square diagonal matrix

Tags: javascript, tensorflow

Let's see an easy example, I have a tensor `[1,2]`. The position of `1` is `[0]`, the position of `2` is `[1]`. I want to transform this 1d tensor into 2d, where the position of

- `1` would turn from `[0]` to `[0, 0]`
- `2` would turn from `[1]` to `[1, 1]`
  to make the new tensor look like this:

```js
[
  [1, 0],
  [0, 2],
]
```

Is there a method for that?

Comment: Like diagonal matrix? I.e. `[1,2,3]` would turn to `[[1,0,0],[0,2,0],[0,0,3]]`?

Comment: Exactly, that's what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you need to transform the list of items into [square diagonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_matrix#:%7E:text=In%20linear%20algebra%2C%20a%20diagonal,by%2D3%20diagonal%20matrix%20is), you may use 2 nested [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to build up *2d-structure*:

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5],

      listToMatrix = a =>
        a.map((_,i) => 
          a.map((e, j) => 
            i == j ? e : 0))
          
console.log(listToMatrix(arr))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Comment: Would be useful if tensorflow would have this method, however, if solved by arrays, can't think of a better way to solve it.